# JPA - OneToMany association between person and address but cannot create @NamedQuery with association

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

i am new to hibernate and jpa. Basically i have 2 tables Person and Address. A person can have many address. I have a OnetoMany relationship between person and address. I want to get the firstname and the address of each person.

Please find below my 2 tables:

```
ADDRESS: ADDRESSID,ADDRESS,PERSONID

PERSON:ID, FIRTSNAME,LASTNAME,PASSWORD.
```

I don't know the syntax about how to create the  @NamedQuery for the corresponding sql below:

```
select PERSON.FIRSTNAME, ADDRESS.ADDRESS
FROM PERSON
INNER JOIN ADDRESS
ON PERSON.id = ADDRESS.PERSONID;
```

Please find the address entity class and i am assuming the select statement will be in the class below:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="getAddressWithPersonFirstName",query=" ")
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {

@Id
@Column(name = "ADDRESSID")
private int addressId;

@Column(name = "ADDRESS")
private String address;

@Column(name = "PERSONID")
private int personId;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="personId")
private Person person;


public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
}

public void setPerson(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
}

public int getAddressId() {
    return addressId;
}

public void setAddressId(int addressId) {
    this.addressId = addressId;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public int getPersonId() {
    return personId;
}

public void setPersonId(int personId) {
    this.personId = personId;
}
```

}

My second entity class:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1308795024262635690L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column
private String firstName;

@Column
private String lastName;

@Column
private String password;
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Address.class, mappedBy = "person")
private List<Address> address;


public List<Address> getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(List<Address> address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public Person() {
}

public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return super.toString() + " name = " + firstName + " " + lastName
            + " id = " + id;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Person other = (Person) obj;
    if (firstName == null) {
        if (other.firstName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
        return false;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    if (lastName == null) {
        if (other.lastName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

Please find he method where i will run my query:

```
    public List<Address> getAddressByPersonFirstName() {

    TypedQuery<Address> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(
            "getAddressWithPersonFirstName", Address.class);
    List<Address> results = query.getResultList();
    return results;

}
```

So as stated above my two main issues are how to create the @NamedQuery to find all address with a person name and i am not sure if the above method is right since i will return address and person name but my method above returns an object Address.:(

Any help is most welcome.thnks again

Answer (score 1):

So, first thing you want to do is double check your Person class.  Your address class has @Table(name="ADDRESS") and the @Entity, but I don't see these for the Person class.  Make sure Person class is mapped to the PERSON Table.

Based on what you are describing, I don't think you even need a named query to do what you want to do.  It looks like you want to select all addresses in the database and get the first name of the person associated with that address.  You have mapped your Address to the Person class with your @ManyToOne join.

So first step is getting all the addresses.  There are a few ways to do that, you can try:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select a from Address a");
List<Address> addresses = (List<Address>) query.getResultList();
```

This will get you every address in your database.  If you want the first name to go with that address, pull out the individual address from the list:

```
address.getPerson().getFirstName();
```

Now, let's say you wanted to make a named query to do this for a particular first name.  Say you wanted to find all addresses where the person's first name is "Bob."

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="getAddressWithPersonFirstName", query="select a from Address a inner join Person p 
            where p.firstName=:firstName")
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {
```

Then call the named query:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("getAddressWithPersonFirstName")
query.setParameter(0, "Bob");
return (List<Address>) query.list();
```

Comment: Hello thanks a lot for the response and the clear explanation @jacobhyphenated, it did work the first example but the second one with the parameter i am not able to get the getNamedQuery with my entity manager. I have defined entity manager in my class as PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;. Any idea why i am not getting the getNamedQuery method please?

Comment: @user1999453 Try entityManager.createNamedQuery() instead of getNamedQuery(). Let me know if that works.

Comment: Hello @jacobhyphenated, thnks a lot for the response, i tried Query query=entityManager.createNamedQuery("getAddressWithPersonFirstName"); but when i start my tomcat server I have the following error regarding the query:ERROR: org.hibernate.hql.PARSER -  Path expected for join! :(
ERROR: org.hibernate.hql.PARSER -  Invalid path: 'p.firstName'
ERROR: org.hibernate.hql.PARSER - <AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
ERROR: org.hibernate.hql.PARSER -  left-hand operand of a binary operator was null
ERROR: org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - Error in named query: getAddressByPersonFirstNameParam

Comment: @user1999453 Huh, that's odd.  You could try changing the query to "select a from Address a inner join Person p on p.id = a.personId where p.firstName=:firstName"  I would think that hibernate could figure that out on it's own though.

Comment: thnks @jacobhyphenated, i tried the above query, it looks like hibernate does not recognize the on keyword because i am getting the following error:ERROR: org.hibernate.hql.PARSER - line 1:65: unexpected token: on ERROR: org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - Error in named query: getAddressByPersonFirstNameParam
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: on near line 1, column 65 [select a from com.gemstone.domain.Address a inner join Person p on p.id = a.personId where p.firstName=:firstName]

Comment: @user1999453  Really, the on should not even be necessary.  Sorry that did not work.  I would look at the part of the error where Address shows up as com.gemstone.domain.Address but Person does not have a qualified package name.  Make sure all the hibernate mappings in Person are correct.